# SHA 256/512 with salted using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Kindly help me with to insert password into database using SHA 256/512 with salted in codeigniter framework. Find below code which is not exactly as per my understanding in SHA 256/541.

Javascript Code

```
if(document.frm_login.password.value!="")
                
{
                
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(document.frm_login.password.value, "");
                
$('#passwords').text('');
                document.frm_login.password.value=mixUpValues(hash.toString(),document.frm_login.keyy.value,document.frm_login.keyy1.value);    
                }
```

User Model

```
public  function findMd5Value($mixValue)
    {       
        $password = substr($mixValue, 0, 12);

        $password.= substr($mixValue, 22, 10);

        $password.= substr($mixValue, 37);

        return $password;

    }
```

User Controller

```
$dataform=$request->getPost();

    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";

    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array

    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {

    $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);

    $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];

    }

    $randomPassword=implode($pass); //turn the array into a string

    $dataform['password']=$randomPassword;
```

Comment: so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: First of all I am not able to understand CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 function will create a SHA 256 encrypted string and here findMd5Value() function is used which I can understood it will create a md5 encrypted string. I want to create password using SHA 256/512 in my codeigniter project.Kindly help.

Comment: I understand in model with function insert() used hash_hmac('sha256', $dataform['password'], '') which is without salt and to add salt I have to create a variable like $salt = 'xxxxxxxx'; and concatenate that $salt variable in hash_hmac('sha256', $dataform['password'].$salt, '');. I hope I am right?